# Mixed-ANOVA or GLMM?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to understand if I should go for a Mixed-ANOVA or a GLMM analysis on my data.
My experiment was as follows:

**Independent variables**:

1. Water Temperature (14ºC and 20ºC)
2. Air Temperature (28ºC, 36ºC, 38ºC, 40ºC)
3. Region (Population)

**Dependent variable**:

1. Growth

Shortly, I sampled a species of algae from 10 populations, scattered along 3 diferent regions (4 populations from South of Europe, 4 populations from central of Europe and 2 populations from north of Europe). I then conducted in laboratory an experiment with 8 treatments (4 levels of air temperature and 2 levels of water temperature, factorial design: 4x2).

The intention was to see if there were differences between the regions, where the populations are suppost to replicates of the region.

My analysis should be Mixed since my population variable is nested in the regional effect, correct?
About the indepdent variables, temperatures I decided on my experiment, should this be a categorical or a continuous variable? If I consider this continuous, I'll have to go GLMM (because ANOVA only deals with categorical.

Hope I was clear enough to get valid opinions.

Thank you so much.

Cheers, Luís Pereira.